# How to debug on client's PC in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging

My application is Excel AddIn, I need debug on client's PC to figure out an issue.

install a debug version of my addin, copy all pdb files to client's PC (Win 7 64 bit, office 2010 32 bit)
also copy x64 C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\Remote Debugger
from my PC to client

Then I start client's Excel,  then run msvsmon.exe

Now in visual studio 2010 on my PC, I try to do debug->attach to process 
I put client's domain\client's PC name in qualifier field,  and refresh.
I got this message "Unalbe to connect to the Microsoft Visual Studio Remote Debugging Monitor named ****. The required name is valid, but no data of the requested type was found."

I wonder how can I debug on client's PC. of course client's PC is on different domain from mine. 
BTW my PC has win 7 64 bit, too

Thanks